# ontouchstart remove ahover in ipad iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button have a:hover effect.
however I want to disable hover in ipad and iphone.
it's not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".content").hide();
            $(".open1").click(function () {
                $(this).next().slideToggle(400);

                if('ontouchstart' in document){$('#btn_01').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');}

                var btn = $('#btn_01'), isOn = btn.hasClass('on');              
                if(isOn) { btn.removeClass('on'); }
                else if(btn) { btn.addClass('on'); }
                });
        });

<style type="text/css">

    #btn_01{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_on.png') no-repeat;}
        #btn_01:hover{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
        #btn_01.on{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Your `else if(btn) {` will always be true because `jQuery("wrong-selector")` also returns a jQuery Object. If you want to test for an empty selection, you can use `if ( $("wrong-selector").length )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a very easy way to solve this porblem, use css @media
i change hover's image to original image.

```
#btn_01{btn_01_on.png'}
#btn_01:hover{btn_01_on.png'}
#btn_01.on{btn_01_over.png'}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
#btn_01{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_on.png') no-repeat;}
#btn_01:hover{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_on.png') no-repeat;}
#btn_01.on{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a difference approach:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var className = ('ontouchstart' in document ) ? "touch-device" : "desktop-device";

    $(document.body).addClass(className);
});
```

Then you can specify the tweaks in your style using `body.desktop-device` and `body.touch-device`:

```
body.desktop-device #btn_01:hover {
    background: red;
}
body.touch-device #btn_01 {
    background: blue;
}
```

---

```
var a = b ? c : d;

//means:

if ( b ) {
    var a = c;
}
else {
    var a = d;
}
```